# c++ Nested Iterator problem through Vector of Structs

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ so forgive my newbishness.

I'm trying to loop through a deque of structs. in each of these structs, there's a struct member that is itself a vector of a different struct. I'm trying to find unique values of these nested structs, and if i find a nested struct item is not unique, i want to delete the parent struct from the deque. I refer to each parent struct as a "split".

Here are my structures:

```
// struct for each action inside each "split".
struct act_struct {
    short int csv_card_index;
    short int act_type;
    short int act_mod1;
    short int act_mod2;
};

// struct for each individual split, the parent struct
struct split_struct {    
    std::vector<short int> cards_in_hand;
    std::vector<short int> cards_drawn;
    std::vector<short int> cards_in_deck;
    std::vector<short int> cards_bf;
    std::vector<short int> cards_mana_disabled;
    std::vector<act_struct> actions;  <--- this is where the act_struct gets nested
    bool played_a_land;
};

// deque holding different split_structs in sequence
typedef std::deque<split_struct> all_splits_que;
```

So like I said, i want to loop through the deque all_splits_que, which has a bunch of split_struct. I then. what to access each split_struct's "actions" member. I want to see if those sequence of actions are unique among all of the "actions" members in all split_struct items, and if not, delete the split_struct from its deque.

Here is my initial code that attempts to get to that point:

```
// this is a vector where I'll track action vectors i've already encountered, so I can tell
// if the current action vector is unique. if the current action vector is unique, it will get push
// onto this
std::vector<std::vector<act_struct>> used_action_sequences;

// all_splits is an all_splits_que with several split_struct in sequence

// first i create an iterator to loop through all_splits
auto it = all_splits.begin();

while ( it != all_splits.end() ) {
    
    // access the actions struct for this split_struct
    std::vector<act_struct> this_split_acts = it->actions;
    
    // create a new iterator that checks if this_split_acts is already found in 
    // used_action_sequences (ERROR THROWN ON THIS LINE)
    std::vector<std::vector<act_struct>>::iterator it2 = std::find(used_action_sequences.begin(), used_action_sequences.end(), this_split_acts);

}
```

This is as far as i can get, as it doesnt seem to like me creating a second iterator. I use gcc in Geany, this is the first group of errors logged. I don't know what they mean. What am I doing wrong? I tried replacing the type of iterator it2 with "auto" and get the same errors. thanks.

```
In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/ios:40,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:3:
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of 'static bool std::__equal<_BoolType>::equal(_II1, _II1, _II2) [with _II1 = const act_struct*; _II2 = const act_struct*; bool _BoolType = false]':
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:851:43:   required from 'bool std::__equal_aux(_II1, _II1, _II2) [with _II1 = const act_struct*; _II2 = const act_struct*]'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:1069:30:   required from 'bool std::equal(_II1, _II1, _II2) [with _II1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const act_struct*, std::vector<act_struct> >; _II2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const act_struct*, std::vector<act_struct> >]'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:1890:21:   required from 'bool std::operator==(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = act_struct; _Alloc = std::allocator<act_struct>]'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/bits/predefined_ops.h:241:17:   required from 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<act_struct>*, std::vector<std::vector<act_struct> > >; _Value = const std::vector<act_struct>]'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:120:14:   required from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<act_struct>*, std::vector<std::vector<act_struct> > >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::vector<act_struct> >]'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:161:23:   required from '_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<act_struct>*, std::vector<std::vector<act_struct> > >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const std::vector<act_struct> >]'
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:3899:28:   required from '_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::vector<act_struct>*, std::vector<std::vector<act_struct> > >; _Tp = std::vector<act_struct>]'        
main.cpp:296:145:   required from here
```

Comment: all_splits, as i explain in the comment, is an all_splits_que with several split_structs. And I'm not comparing 2 structs, I'm seeing if a vector of structs is found in a bunch of vector of structs.

Comment: @GeoffL please edit your question to give the definition of `all_splits`. Why `std::vector<act_struct> this_split_acts = it->actions;` rather than `const std::vector<act_struct> & this_split_acts = it->actions;` ? I mean at least to use a reference to not copy the vector and while you do not use to modify it better to also have `const`

Comment: Its probably unable to understand how to compare 2 `std::vector<act_struct>` objects.

Comment: I think you are correct, it doesnt know how to compare the two. I tried replacing the second iterator it2 with a simpler iterator checking some simple vector of ints for an int, and it was ok with that. So how can i check if a vector of a vector of structs contains a certain vector of structs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `operator==` on *act_struct* because it is needed by `std::find` to compare two `std::vector<act_struct>`

Example :

```
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

// struct for each action inside each "split".
struct act_struct {
    short int csv_card_index;
    short int act_type;
    short int act_mod1;
    short int act_mod2;
    friend bool operator==(const act_struct & v1, const act_struct & v2) {
       return v1.csv_card_index == v2.csv_card_index; // <<< ADDED >>>
    }
};

// struct for each individual split, the parent struct
struct split_struct {    
    std::vector<short int> cards_in_hand;
    std::vector<short int> cards_drawn;
    std::vector<short int> cards_in_deck;
    std::vector<short int> cards_bf;
    std::vector<short int> cards_mana_disabled;
    std::vector<act_struct> actions;  //<--- this is where the act_struct gets nested
    bool played_a_land;
};

// deque holding different split_structs in sequence
typedef std::deque<split_struct> all_splits_que;

int main()
{
  
  // this is a vector where I'll track action vectors i've already encountered, so I can tell
  // if the current action vector is unique. if the current action vector is unique, it will get push
  // onto this
  std::vector<std::vector<act_struct>> used_action_sequences;
  
  // all_splits is an all_splits_que with several split_struct in sequence
  all_splits_que all_splits; // <<< ADDED >>>
  
  // first i create an iterator to loop through all_splits
  auto it = all_splits.begin();
  
  while ( it != all_splits.end() ) {
    
    // access the actions struct for this split_struct
    std::vector<act_struct> this_split_acts = it->actions; // better to have const ref
    
    // create a new iterator that checks if this_split_acts is already found in 
    // used_action_sequences 
    std::vector<std::vector<act_struct>>::iterator it2 = std::find(used_action_sequences.begin(), used_action_sequences.end(), this_split_acts);

  }
}
```

Compilation :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall c.cc
c.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
c.cc:49:52: warning: variable ‘it2’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     std::vector<std::vector<act_struct>>::iterator it2 = std::find(used_action_sequences.begin(), used_action_sequences.end(), this_split_acts);
                                                    ^~~
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Probably the right `operator==` on *act_struct* has to compare all the fields, I put a pseudo definition just to show the code compile

As I said in a remark I encourage you to replace

> ```
> std::vector<act_struct> this_split_acts = it->actions;
> ```

by

```
const std::vector<act_struct> & this_split_acts = it->actions;
```

and probably

> ```
> std::vector<std::vector<act_struct>>::iterator it2
> ```

can be

```
 std::vector<std::vector<act_struct>>::const_iterator it2
```

Comment: @GeoffL you welcome, to be frank I supposed d4rk4ng31 will put an answer and was waiting he does, and then decided to put mine after a 'timeout' ^^

Comment: @bruno, Its fine (Had to be AFK for a while :P). All that matters is the question got answered and we were able to help someone :).

Comment: @GeoffL, Also, take a look at how bruno's compiled the code. It is usually a good practice to turn on all compiler warnings for efficient debugging

Comment: @bruno again thanks for your answer. I have a question. when compare the 2 vectors of act_structs, will it matter the order that the act_structs appear in each vector with the changes you've made, or does it just check if the vectors contain the same act_structs?

Comment: @GeoffL, For more information, take a [look](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp), also, please UV this answer like I did, if you found it nice :)

Comment: @GeoffL to be equals two vectors must contains the same elements at the same position, so first they need to have the same number of elements. 'same' meaning `operator==` returns true

Comment: +, in this case, the definition you've written for your custom `operator==` also matters :)